# What happens if I add PackageReference net46 in a NET Core library?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I would like to create a library in NET Core that I could use in WPF applications and also in a future application in android. So it is why I was thinking in a NET Core library.

However, if I add the reference to this project in my WPF project, the reference has a yellow triangle, I guess because they are not compatible.

So in the csproject file in my NET Core library, I add in the propertyGroup this:

```
<TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
```

So now I can reference in my WPF project with no problems. However, I am wondering how this affects to the library. I mean, if I will can use in a android application or not, because how it references to NET Framework, perhaps the NET Core library now depends on it and how NET Framework is not available on android, I am thinking that perhaps I can't use it.

So, how does it affect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF projects, and .NET framework applications in general, can't reference .NET Core libraries. They are in different parts of the Microsoft ecosystem.

However, both .NET Core projects and .NET framework projects can use .NET **Standard** libraries (Xamarin can also). You just need to target a version of .NET Standard that all your platforms support.

You can find a full explanation of .NET Standard, as well as see what platforms support which versions of it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library.

Comment: Then, I need my WPF project, my NET Core project and a third project that it would be NET Standard? But what could have this third project?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía You only need the .NET Core project if you actually have an application targeting that platform (unlikely since Core doesn't have a UI tech yet). I'm not sure I understand your second question; a .NET Standard library is a *library*. It goes wherever you normally put libraries

Comment: I wanted to mean, NET Standard what version of NET uses? The code that I would write in this library, it would be net46, NET Core or another version of NET? At first I wanted to use NET Core because I have readed that it has better performance than NET Famework, so I don't know if with NET Standard I would have the advtanges of NET Core or not.

I know that perhaps I am confusing two different things, I am trying to clear my ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía No, you would not have the speed advantage of .NET Core. .NET Standard is just a way to share code between .NET Framework, .NET Core, and Xamarin applications. The library code runs on the same framework as the using application.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía note that you can multitarget your library to both net46 and netstandard. It will be then compiled for both platforms (two separate dlls). You should do this only if you need something outside netstandard. Of course you will be able to use such functionality only in net version, but codebase will be mostly shared.